# Ingest utility doesn't insert NULL value in a column of integer type

Tags: db2, data-ingestion, ingest

I am reading a CSV file through a named pipe. In the CSV file the field2 column is  blank which need to be inserted into a table column as NULL. The table column is of type integer, but When I try to run the ingest

I am getting an error that says 'field2 cannot be converted to the value type: integer'.

Here is my below code

```
mkfifo mypipe
tail -n +2 myfile.csv > mypipe &

db2 "INGEST FROM FILE mypipe 
   FORMAT DELIMITED 
   (
      $field1 CHAR(9),
      $field2 INTEGER EXTERNAL,
      $field3 CHAR(32)
   )
   INSERT INTO my_table 
      VALUES($field1, $field2, $field3)"
```

In the above code, $field2 will be blank. In the my_table, $field2 value doesn't get inserted as NULL when the field is blank in csv.

Sample input csv data as shown below

```
Subject_Name,Student_ID,STATUS
Maths,,COMPLETED
Physics,,PENDING
Computers,,PENDING
```

I want the data to be ingested in the table like below

```
Subject_Name|Student_id|STATUS   |
------------|----------|---------|
Maths       |NULL      |COMPLETED|
------------|----------|---------|
Physics     |NULL      |PENDING  |
------------|----------|---------|
Computers   |NULL      |PENDING  |
------------|----------|---------|
```

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Either use a text file with your original command as is or escape the `$` characters with "\", if you want to run this command from a shell command prompt.

Comment: yes @Mark I am using the '\' to escape the $ to run this command but the problem i am facing occurs when the command runs and cannot insert the blank as integer. Is there any way that i can replace the value as NULL when the field2 value is blank ?

Comment: @vineeth Please edit your question to show exactly one sample line from the csv input. Specifically how the second column appears when blank. If it looks like `filed1,,field3` then it should work. But if the second column appears as `field1,'',field3` then it should fail.

Comment: @mao I have edit the question to show the sample input csv and the expected output.
Can you suggest some way to achieve this ?

Comment: @mao i have edited the question with raw data.

Comment: @vineeth, I cannot recreate your symptom, with that format. The ingest command in my case correctly converts the `,,` (the blank/empty field-2) into a NULL.  What is the plain text output of the `db2level` command when run on the Db2-SERVER hostname?